# Creating a responsive site without Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my heavily customised Opencart 1.5x store responsive, but without using Bootstrap due to conflicts and issues I have encountered trying to go the Bootstrap way.

I am hoping too add the same 5 BS media section sizes in my stylesheet(1200,979,767,480,320) then just change my container id size and one or two other divs that need changing.

```
<--Example Media CSS code in stylesheet.css "1 of 5"-->
 @media screen (max-width: 1200px){
#logo { 
   // margin code here
}
}

<--HTML Stylesheet Links-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/*/stylesheet/stylesheet.css" />
```

Should I stick with a link in the header to my stylesheet or do I need a media stylesheet or a reference to media in the listings alongside my usual stylesheet?

Comment: code your style-sheets (height/width) `%` (percentage) vise.

Comment: You can put media queries at the end of your stylesheet or in a separate stylesheet loaded in after your main stylesheet (css overwrites with the last rule for the same specificity)

Comment: @GaurangJoshi Have you got an example? Do you mean stick with one stylesheet or have 1 for each of the 5 media widths?